# Python: Boolean does not work as expected

Tags: python

Example is very simple:

```
a = 2
b = 7

a >= 1 & a <= 10**10 & b >= 1 & b <= 10**2
>False
a >= 1 & a <= 10**2 & b >= 1 & b <= 10**2
>True
```

This problem came to me as a simple typo. And got me curious. But in the end I can't really understand why does it behave like that?

Comment: `&` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Use `and`, instead of `&`.

Comment: Ouch... There goes my attempt to experiment with different languages. Even common operators are different.

Comment: This post deserves a delete. And I deserve to fix my dignity by starting all over with reading Python manual from page 1. *sigh*

Comment: @A.Val. `&` means bitwise AND in almost all C-influenced languages. If logical AND is written with the "&" symbol, it's almost always as `&&`.

Comment: @Ben I've been using exclusively R language for data analytics for last few years. That might explain this problem... Apparently re-learning syntax from scratch will be a bumpy ride. Thanks for explaining though.

Comment: @A.Val. please consider accepting the answer since it solved your question

Comment: @Idos I don't really mind... I just thought it is inappropriate for duplicated questions with answer linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [logical AND](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/logical_operators_example.htm) operator which is `and` in Python, and not `&`.

```
>>> a >= 1 and a <= 10**10 and b >= 1 and b <= 10**2
True
```